# Using custom NodeJS module that require 3rd party module into NuxtJs3

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, babeljs, es6-modules

I'm digging into custom module creation, and I've been able to

- create custom scoped package (i.e. it starts with '@')
- transpile it with [`babel`](https://babeljs.io/)
- publish it to private gitlab registry
- import it as a dependency into a Nuxt 3 project
- use it in a page with no problem (the web app is compiled to static assets via `nuxt generate`)

At this point the custom package is just exporting a bunch of test stuff, i.e. a string, a number, a function and an object.

To test the creation of a more complex package, I tried to import and use a 3rd party module into mine (i.e. I imported [`Pinia`](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) and exported a simple store created via Pinia's `defineStore`), but now whenn running `nuxt generate` I get a lots of errors, all in the form of

```
Can't import the named export 'XXXX' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
```

and all fired from my package transpiled `index.js`.

Removing the `import { defineStore } from "pinia";` from my package and rely on the Nuxt project to make it available make `nuxt generate` running properly but then the page doesn't work (obviously) and a `ReferenceError: _pinia is not defined` error is logged.

I just approached both custom module creation and `babeljs`, so propbabily I'm missing something about how to correctly write a custom package or about `babeljs` configuration.

##### Custom package source (non transpiled) file

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useTestStore = defineStore({
    id: 'testStore',
    state: () => {
        return {
            a: 1,
            b: 'ciao'
        }
    },
    actions: {
        testAction(x) {
            return x + 1;
        },
    },
});

export const testString = 'my string';
export const testNumber = 3.14;
export const testObject = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
};

export function testFunction(x) {
    return x + 1;
}

export default function testDefaultFunction(x) {
    console.log(x);
}
```